# Retrieving the Text Style for a UITextfield

Tags: ios, swift

I try getting the text style for a UITextField. I have set the style (Font Text Styles - Subhead) in the attribute inspector in the Interface Builder.

In my app try to react on a font size change. Theirfor I need the text style.

Is their a way to retrieve this information.  I don't want to set the text style in code, because I develop a reusable component, that could use within the IB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [UITextFIeld Class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/font) and [UIFont Class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFont_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/UIFont)

```
@IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!

    ...    

    let fontInfo = textField.font
    println(fontInfo.fontName)
    println(fontInfo.familyName)
    println(fontInfo.pointSize)
```

### Edit - added specific code to check text style

```
    let textStyle = fontInfo.fontDescriptor().fontAttributes()["NSCTFontUIUsageAttribute"] as String

    switch textStyle {
    case UIFontTextStyleBody:
        println("Body")
        break
    case UIFontTextStyleCaption1:
        println("Caption1")
        break
    case UIFontTextStyleCaption2:
        println("Caption2")
        break
    case UIFontTextStyleFootnote:
        println("Footnote")
        break
    case UIFontTextStyleHeadline:
        println("Headline")
        break
    case UIFontTextStyleSubheadline:
        println("SubHeadline")
        break
    default:
        println("Default")
        break
    }
```

Comment: With this I get only the "real" font dimensions. What I'm locking for is:   UIFontTextStyleHeadline, UIFontTextStyleSubheadline, ...   

  

[UIFontDescriptor](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFontDescriptor_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIFontTextStyleHeadline)  
With this information I can reapply the correct font descriptor to the text field  
        floatingLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleCaption2)

Comment: use UIFont.fontDescriptor()